# Trouble setting up MX records Digital Ocean

Tags: networking, dns, digital-ocean, mail-server, mx-record

I'm trying to set up MX records on Digital Ocean to point to a german 1and1 mailserver.

1and1 say that my provider Digital Ocean has to change my mail servers to
mx01.kundenserver.de with the priority 11
mx00.kundenserver.de with the priority 10

I believe I have done this on DO but it's still not working, have I missed something?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mx00.kundenserver.de` is the name of the mail server of your provider (1and1).

Try setting the hostname of your MX record to e.g. `mail` or `@`, the mail providers mail server to `mx00.kundenserver.de` and the priority 10.

Similar for the second entry, just set the priority to 20.

Comment: thanks for replying I realised the mistake this morning needed to @ in the hostname and mx00.kundenserver.de under mailserver